# Fill a Range with Nulls

Tags: excel, vba

I need to fill a range of cells with a Null.
I am currently using:

```
Sub FillARangeWithNulls()
Dim DQ As String
DQ = Chr(34)
With Selection
    .Clear
    .Formula = "=" & DQ & DQ
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
End Sub
```

This code works, but it seems a little complex for this simple task.  I am hoping for something like:

```
Sub WhatIWouldLike()
Selection.Value = ???????????????
End Sub
```

but I can't find the correct string to use

Comment: When you say Null, what do you mean? A string of zero length? #N/A?

Comment: @Bathsheba  Yes  I mean a single NULL character

Comment: OK. I assume that you mean a zero length of string; answer below.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent suggest using `Selection.Value = vbNullString` which is the quicker - and more explicit version - of `Selection.Value = ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
Sub WhatIWouldLike()
    Selection.Value = ""
End Sub
```

which will set every cell in the selection to a blank string; as you say you want in your comment.

But note that this is **not** the same as a cell that hasn't been touched. To do that use ClearContents as @mehow or @Cody Piersall states.

Comment: Your code works, but only if I first format the cells to Text.  I can do this within the macro.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you need it to be text just add `Selection.NumberFormat = "@"` before the `Selection.Value = ""`

Answer (score 2):

you can also use

```
With Selection
   .Value = "'"
   .ClearFormats
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub WhatIWouldLike()
    Selection.ClearContents 
End Sub
```